# Driver not working for Netgear A6210 USB Adapter Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers

Before you mark this as duplicate know that I have read the other posts and the answers do not fix my problem. Basically to summarize what I am dealing with: I have the adapter plugged in and the driver downloaded and setup but no wifi signals are coming through besides my temporary Ethernet cable through my phone.

I have blacklisted my old wifi card as it was absolutely horrible getting about .01mb download. This has led my top right wifi menu to only list my ethernet device and its connection.

To get the neccesary router for the A6210 I used the following steps:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210
$ cd Netgear-A6210
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

After getting that all installed I plugged in my adapter and nothing happened. I figured maybe I had to reboot so I did that but still to no avail. At this point I feel as though I have all the necessary parts just not the end product. Also added note: I can't use the NdisWrapper method because the driver that is only available for windows 10 cannot be extracted.

Lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 13d3:3414 IMC Networks 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1532:0504 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c335 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 046d:c07d Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 0846:9053 NetGear, Inc. 
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Ifconfig:

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:a0:50:86:4c:27  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp3s0u1c4i2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1a:65:90:84:0f:6e  
          inet addr:172.20.10.3  Bcast:172.20.10.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: 2607:fb90:984:a0a8:1dee:5519:507c:ca80/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2607:fb90:984:a0a8:4dc6:1bba:e81a:4dc4/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::4fb5:e8:49ed:e7b1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10214 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9553 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9443066 (9.4 MB)  TX bytes:1135816 (1.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:124400 (124.4 KB)  TX bytes:124400 (124.4 KB)
```

Dmesg | tail:

```
[   24.424151]  [<ffffffff83851891>] start_secondary+0x151/0x190
[   24.424152] ---[ end trace 1545bb3f3c099b63 ]---
[   24.424154] ipheth 8-1:4.2: ipheth_tx_timeout: TX timeout
[  806.010958] usb 9-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  806.791227] usb 9-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  806.815783] usb 9-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0846, idProduct=9053
[  806.815787] usb 9-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  806.815790] usb 9-2: Product: A6210
[  806.815793] usb 9-2: Manufacturer: NETGEAR
[  806.815795] usb 9-2: SerialNumber: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the solution to my problem so here is the fix I found in case you are running into the same dillema.

When I attempted to use the command `sudo modprobe mt7662u_sta` it reports that the public key was not available. To fix this I had to disable secure boot in the UEFI BIOS page on startup. This can be easily accomplised by pressing `ESC, F1, F2`, or whatever your system requires on startup.

After doing that and rebooting I entered the modprobe command again and the wifi popped up.

Comment: " To fix this I had to disable secure boot in the UEFI BIOS page on startup." Yes... secure boot is useless and doesn't allow you to install some proprietary drivers such as some very common Realtek Ethernet devices and as i can see that goes for the mediatek wifi drivers-firmware  too.